# Determine the maximum value of the sum $S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n}} (a_1a_2…a_n)^{1/n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, infinite-product

Determine the maximum value of the sum $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n}} (a_1a_2…a_n)^{1/n} $$ over all sequences $a_k$ of non negative real numbers satisfying $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k =1.$$
I have an idea to solve this that the product may be transformed into sum by using AM-GM inequality? If I take $$\frac{a_1+a_2+…+a_n}{n}\ge (a_1a_2…a_n)^{1/n}$$ I reach to a wrong answer since all $a_k$ can’t be equal together so what other adjustment can be done?
In a solution I got, they by default assumed it to be a GP with common ratio $1/4$ and $a_1=3/4$ but I wonder why did they choose this only?

Attempt $2$: If I assume it to be a GP of first term $a_1=a$ common $r$ then I get $\frac{a}{1-r}=1$ and putting this in $S$, I got $$S=a \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^{n}}(1-a)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}$$ Now how can I proceed (maybe through derivatives but how?)?

I’m not attaching the official solution since I want a method other than that. As mentioned above they take $a=3/4$ and $r=1/4$ arbitrarily to solve but the question is why this pair only?

Comment: Don't there exist solutions to the Putnam problems?

Comment: I got a solution but I couldn’t understand it.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: I have to admit, this problem is unreasonably closed. OP is making a genuine effort to ask a good question and included his thoughts and steps. Unfortunately, I do not have the reputation to cast reopen votes, but if anyone reading this has, consider reopening this question.

Comment: This question in its current state indeed should be closed. If there is a specific part of the solution you cannot understand, please include that information, otherwise people will simply post the same answer over and over again, not solving your actual confusion. People are not mind-readers after all.

Comment: @Trebor I mentioned your point in my post

Comment: what do you mean you are not attaching the official solution ? In what exact ways, this post will deteriorate if you did ? Besides, I sincerely doubt that the official solution omitted the part that the optimal input will have to be a geometric series, which is much more important than figuring out which geometric series.

Comment: Also, the official solution does use AM-GM correctly and does justify that the optimal input has to be a geometric series. So please refrain from spreading false information.

Comment: They don’t explain why they take common ratio 1/4, they just apply AM-GM on $4a_1,4^2a_2…$ without justifying why powers of 4 are multiplied and this was the confusion which is now proved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how to prove that the optimal solution is geometric, but if you assume it is, you have for all $n$, $a_n = a_1r^{n - 1}$ for some $0 \leqslant r < 1$ and $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n = \frac{a_1}{1 - r} = 1$ hence $a_1 = 1 - r$. From here, you have for all $n$,
$$
\frac{n}{2^n}(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n} = (1 - r)\frac{n}{2^n}(r^0\cdots r^{n - 1})^{1/n} = (1 - r)\frac{n}{2^n}r^{(n - 1)/2} = \frac{1 - r}{2}n\left(\frac{\sqrt{r}}{2}\right)^{n - 1}.
$$
Now, use the fac that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} x^n = \frac{1}{1 - x} - 1$ and differentiate this equality to deduce that $\sum_{n \geqslant 1} nx^{n - 1} = \frac{1}{(1 - x)^2}$. Therefore,
$$
\sum_{n \geqslant 1} \frac{n}{2^n}(a_1\cdots a_n)^{1/n} = \frac{1 - r}{2}\sum_{n \geqslant 1} n\left(\frac{\sqrt{r}}{2}\right)^{n - 1} = \frac{1 - r}{2}\frac{1}{\left(1 - \frac{\sqrt{r}}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{2 - 2r}{(2 - \sqrt{r})^2}.
$$
It means that we must find the $r$ between $0$ and $1$ that maximizes $f(r) = \frac{2 - 2r}{(2 - \sqrt{r})^2}$. We have if $0 < r < 1$,
\begin{align*}
f'(r) & = \frac{-2 \cdot (2 - \sqrt{r})^2 - (2 - 2r) \cdot 2\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{r}}(2 - \sqrt{r})}{(2 - \sqrt{r})^4}\\
& = \frac{-2\sqrt{r}(2 - \sqrt{r}) + 2 - 2r}{\sqrt{r}(2 - \sqrt{r})^3}\\
& = \frac{2 - 4\sqrt{r}}{\sqrt{r}(2 - \sqrt{r})^3}
\end{align*}
Therefore, $f'(r)$ vanishes at $r = 1/4$, is positive before and negative after. We deduce that $r = 1/4$ is the optimal value and in this case, the sum is $f(1/4) = \frac{2 - 2\frac{1}{4}}{\left(2 - \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}}\right)^2} = \frac{2 - \frac{1}{2}}{\left(2 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2} = \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your solution. I by mistake wrote the wrong answer initially.

Answer (score 3):

What @Jorge wrote should be very helpful to see why we choose $r=1/4$. I will try to explain in more depth the complications your initial approach had and the motivation for choosing a geometric sequence.

**Your Initial Approach**

As you noted, if we try to attack the problem immediately with AM-GM, we get the following:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}\prod_{j=1}^na_j^{1/n} \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{n}{2^n}a_j = \sum_{j \ge 1}\sum_{n\ge j} \frac{1}{2^n}a_j = \sum_{j\ge 1} 2^{1-j}a_j.(1)$$

However, there isn't much we can do here since all we know is $\sum_{j\ge 1 } a_j = 1$.

**Motivation for Steps Forward**

We should strive to manipulate the expression $\frac{n}{2^n}\prod_{j=1}^na_j^{1/n}$ such that when AM-GM is applied, and we flip the sum for simplification $\sum_{j\ge 0} a_j$ pops out.

If you play with the expression some before applying AM-GM, multiplying and dividing out numbers to the $a_j$'s, you'll see that you can affect the resulting coefficients of the $a_j$'s in your upper bound. So let's try to play with the coefficients in a very controlled manner using a sequence, say $\{r_j\}_{j \ge 1}$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^n r_k^{1/n}} \prod_{j=1}^n (a_jr_j)^{1/n}
 \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^n r_k^{1/n}}\sum_{j=1}^n a_jr_j
 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{a_jr_j}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^nr_k^{1/n}} $$.

$$=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} \frac{a_jr_j}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^nr_k^{1/n}} =
 \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j r_j\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n\prod_{k=1}^nr_k^{1/n}}.(2)$$

At this point this point, the only hope is if we consider $\{r_k\}_{k \ge 1}$ as a geometric sequence; otherwise the calculation seems intractable. Additionally, we're hinted towards this direction since we'd like the sum in $n$ to be a constant.

**Following Through on a Hope**

(After this point you could refer to Jorge's work, it is fundamentally the same.)

So let $r_k = r^k$:

$$\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j r^{j-1/2}\sum_{n=j}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n r^{\frac{n}{2}}} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j r^{j-1/2}\frac{1}{2^jr^{j/2}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2r^{1/2})^n}   =                                                  
\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\frac{r^{j-1/2}}{2^jr^{j/2}} \frac{2r^{1/2}}{2r^{1/2}-1} = 
 \sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j\frac{ r^{j/2}}{2^{j-1}} \frac{1}{2r^{1/2}-1}= \frac{1}{2r^{1/2}-1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_j \frac{ r^{j/2}}{2^{j-1}}$$.

Remember that we want $\sum_{j\ge1}a_j$ up to some constant so this means that $r^{j/2}/2^{j-1}$ needs to be a constant. We note that $r^{1/2}/1 = c $ and $r/2 = c $; using the ratio of these two equalities, we get $\Rightarrow r^{1/2} = 2 \Rightarrow r = 4$.

This gives us that the sum should be bounded by $\frac{1}{4-1} (\sum_{j \ge 1} a_j ) \frac{4^{j/2}}{2^{j-1}} = \frac{1}{3} (1) \frac{2^j}{2^{j-1}} = \frac{2}{3}$.

The other half of the problem is to find a sequence which meets the upper bound. Once that is done you've shown it's the maximum.

**Takeaway**

My recommendation is that you write out the expanded form in columns and rows of the sum your initial approach gave you (1). Then expand the sum I give in (2). Then, if you stare at (2) expanded long enough, you'll get the impression that the problem is sort of analogous to a double-counting problem (except instead of things being overcounted, they're being undercounted); so perhaps we could use the sequence $\{r_j\}_{j \ge 1}$ to redress this undercounting.

Comment: Thanks now it’s perfectly clear

Answer (score 1):

Let $S = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}\left( \prod_{i=1}^n a_i \right)^\frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{2^n} r^{\frac{i+1}{2}}\left( \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{r^i} \right)^\frac{1}{n} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n} r^{\frac{n+1}{2}}\left( \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{r^i} \right) = $
$= \sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} r^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \frac{a_i}{r^i} $

Now $\sum_{n=i}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} r^{\frac{n+1}{2}} \frac{a_i}{r^i} = \frac{a_i}{\left(4r\right)^\frac{i}{2}} r^\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{r^\frac{1}{2}}{2}\right)^n = \frac{a_ir^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(4r)^{\frac{i}{2}}} \frac{1}{1-\frac{r^{\frac{1}{2}}}{2}} = C\frac{a_i}{(4r)^\frac{i}{2}} $
In order to get useful information, $4r=1$, because that way we can use the bound on the sum of $a_i$.

Comment: So what is the maximum?

Comment: Please explain that at the end what is $a_i$? Shouldn’t it be evaluated in the summation? Also please elaborate a bit your last conclusion.